# Clicking A Link In IE with VBA

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, excel

I'm trying to click a link on a webpage using VBA, however I can't get it to work for some reason.

**IE Sourcecode:**

```
<a class="WhiteboardLink" title="Hazards/Safe Acts" href="javascript:LinkTo('/Whiteboard.aspx?page=HomePage_OBS','Hazards/Safe Acts')" align="center"><img title="Hazards/Safe Acts" border="0" alt="Hazards/Safe Acts" src="/Images/Whiteboard/OBS.jpg" width="100" height="100"><br><span>Hazards/Safe Acts</span></a>

<img title="Hazards/Safe Acts" border="0" alt="Hazards/Safe Acts" src="/Images/Whiteboard/OBS.jpg" width="100" height="100"><br><span>Hazards/Safe Acts</span>

<br/>

<span>Hazards/Safe Acts</span>
```

**VBA code im trying:**

```
For Each ele In IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a")
 If InStr(ele.innerhtml, "OBS.jpg") > 0 Then
 ele.Click

 Exit For

End If
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Step through your code using F8 and examine the elements in the Locals window? Make sure that your `Instr` test is valid, i.e., that the element's `innerHTML` *does8 contain that string? Alternatively try `getElementsByTagName("img")`?

Comment: @DavidZemens that doesn't seem to help, I've stepped through the program and the line `For Each ele In IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a")` is not finding anything in `IE.document.getelementsbytagname("a")` so it skips the entire `For` loop. I changed it to `IMG` but get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
For Each htma In doc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    Set htmImgs = htma.getElementsByTagName("img")
    If Not htmImgs is nothing Then
        If htmImgs(0).getAttribute("src") <> vbNull And InStr(htmImgs(0).getAttribute("src"), "Images/Whiteboard/OBS.jpg") <> 0 Then
            htma.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work either, the source is actually "/Images/Whiteboard/OBS.jpg" as in the HTML, so I tried that too, but it still doesn't find anything at all, I also tried your above code with "img" as the tag reference, but still it found nothing

Comment: I glanced at it a bit too quick and didn't notice that the src attribute was on the img enclosed in the anchor - rather than on this anchor itself. I have reviewed the code above, give this a try. If this still doesn't work - are you able to share the url of your page at all?